# Bootstrap col-6 col-md-4 dont work on phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi first time posting here so be gentle :D

I'm working on my responsive design and this happen. 
There is my code :

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 expertise">
<img src="<?= $value["skill_image"] ?>">
<h5>
    <?= $value["skill_name"] ?>
</h5>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $value["skill_level"]; $i++) {
    ?>
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
<?php
}
for ($i; $i < 5; $i++) {
    ?>
        <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

So i expect my column to be half width on phone device but that didn't work.
[Screen of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhsSY.png)

Any idea ?

If you want to have a look on the website : https://portfolio-sigier.com/

Thanks for all your answers in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a viewport metatag that defines the width and scale. Add the following to your `head`.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: That destroy the rest of my design but it's solve my problems. Some css and it's gona be perfect. Thank you !

Comment: Great! If it answers your question please mark it as the accepted answer to help others @LucSIGIER